# How to pass values to parent tabgroupactivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activitygroup

I have one tabGroupActivity. in this tabGroupActivity I start a new activity called "pideInformacion", in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), pideInformacion.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("pideInformacion", intent);
```

Then, from pideInformacion class the app open a new activity called verMapaGps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, verMapaGps.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("verMapaGps", intent);
```

I would like that in verMapaGps set string value in order to return to pideInformacion class.

I see this way to access to parent activity, but I don't know how can I access to parent activity values to set it.

```
Activity pideInfoActivity = (pideInformacion) getParent();
```

I can't be able to use startActivityForResult because If I use this method, the tabhost hides and I want to tabbar is show in whole application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the string as a static variable and use it in the parent activity.